If a user requests data deletion, how do I find them in GA4?
I understand how to initiative a data deletion request in GA4 using a user ID. What I can't seem to find any information for is how you identify a user who has asked for their data to be deleted?
Is there a way for the user to find their user ID so we can delete that data, or is there a way the can initiate the request themselves to Google who would be able to detect their ID?
There are many resources walking you through the simple process of requesting deletion, but it's Google-generated number and I can't seem to find any instructions on finding that number for a particular user.

You as the owner of GA4 property would need to request the data deletion by submitting data deletion form.
Re: id's
There are a few ways -

Known User - IF a user is logged in or has a user id, you need to ask Google to delete all the records with the parameter user id matching the user's id value.
Unknown user - Unknown users are hard to find, and I am not sure how they get the request. One of the option is to use their Client id and remove all the records based on the Cient Id parameter, however its highly unlikely you will be able to get that.

